# node-mongodb-native how to create index on sub document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

From the mongodb doc:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html?highlight=ensureIndex#ensureIndex

Basically create an index for a sub document consists in write something like `"address.city"`
So far I couldn't do the same.

I tried:

```
index = "category.code";
index = { "category.code": 1 };
index = { "category": {code: 1} };

collection.ensureIndex( index, {unique: true, w: 1}, function(error, data){
        console.log(error ? error : documentName + ': [ensureIndex] ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```

But no index created.

Is there any other solution?
When I do it from the command line via `mongo` it works.

```
db.type.ensureIndex({'category.code':1})
```

But when I run it from a JS script, it doesn't.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

exports.up = function(db, next){
    var documentName = 'type';
    var collection = mongodb.Collection(db, documentName);
    ...
```

I'm using https://npmjs.org/package/mongo-migrate module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works as expected in NodeJS:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function (err, db) {
    db.collection("test").ensureIndex({ "category.code": 1 }, 
        function(err, result) {        
            db.close();
    });
});
```

Displaying the indexes for the collection:

#### Before running code

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.test.getIndexes()
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "test.test",
            "name" : "_id_"
    }
]
```

#### After running code

```
> db.test.getIndexes()
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "test.test",
            "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "category.code" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "test.test",
            "name" : "category.code_1"
    }
]
```

Comment: So, I think it's an issue from the module I'm using, because I don't see any other explanation otherwise. The connection is opened from it but the code is the same so I don't understand why it doesn't works.

Comment: How are you verifying that the index wasn't created?

Comment: I use Genghis which displays all indexes per "table". I just ran `db.type.getIndexes()` right now to check also in command line and it's the same.

Comment: There's hardly anything to the source you pointed at ... are you sure it's working in the right database? It defaults to `host: 'localhost', db: 'my-app', port: 27017`.

Comment: `node node_modules/mongo-migrate -cfg config/custom/mongodb.json -dbn development-migrate -runmm` is the command line I use. Other indexes and data are correctly inserted into the DB.

Comment: My point is, that the connection, etc. are all just the standard NodeJS MongoDB driver functionality. The migrate module doesn't do anything to override the functionality of functions like `ensureIndex`. It's just automating calling your code, ideally with the correct configuration.

Comment: I understand and it's weird for sure, but the connection is fine, else it wouldn't work with simple indexes neither...

Comment: Try dropping all of your indexes and try again. It's valid syntax. There must be another explanation.

Comment: Finally I don't manage my indexes anymore with this stuff to avoid this kind of issue (doesn't fixed btw), I define my indexes in mongoose. Better I think.